# How to create multiple tabs in tkinter with grid , or how to combine grid and pack

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI and so far i have organised the window as it is presented in the following figure, produced by the following python script. My question is, is it possible to create multiple tabs with the grid pack, or is it possible to combine grid and pack?

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
#Title of GUI
master.wm_title('Title')

#Seperate GUI in sections

stepOne = tk.LabelFrame(master, text=" 1. General Heatmaps: ")
stepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='WE', \
             padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
# First tab
l1 = Label(stepOne, text = "Input tilt:") 
l2 = Label(stepOne, text = "Input wind speed:") 
l3=  Label(stepOne, text = "Input path:") 
# grid method to arrange labels in respective 
# rows and columns as specified 
l1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E, pady = 2) 
l2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E, pady = 2) 
l3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = E, pady = 2)

entryTilt = Entry(stepOne)
entryWind = Entry(stepOne)
entryFolder_path=Entry(stepOne)
# this will arrange entry widgets 
entryTilt .grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 2) 
entryWind .grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 2) 
entryFolder_path .grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = 2)  

b1 = Button(stepOne, text = "Run script") 

b1.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = E) 

master.mainloop()
```

[image: GUI window]

Comment: If you want multiple tabs, use the `ttk.Notebook` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use grid and pack inside the same Tk, TopLevel or Frame, however you can use grid and pack in different frames or top levels.

In your case if you wanted to make another frame inside master, like stepOne , you would have to use grid, however inside that new frame you would be able to use grid or pack.